# Populate Random Image Python/Django using staticfiles

Tags: python, django, image, templates, static

Application: Price is Right Game

I'm trying to populate a random image from my static assets folder(I am using assets for images and css files) into one of my templates. The code is working however I'm getting a 404 image not found error. I have a feeling the problem lies within my path.

Another question I have, I also have a random number function, am I able to have both functions in the same file (my_templatetag.py)? I'm getting errors when I have both functions in the same file. I have the random_int number working fine however when I'm trying to work the random_image function, I get a lot of errors.

Thanks for the help

my_templatetag.py (random numbers & images defs)

```
import random, os
from django import template
from django.conf import settings



register = template.Library()
@register.simple_tag
def random_int(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        a, b = 0, a
    return random.randint(a, b)

#Generate random img function
register = template.Library()
@register.simple_tag
def random_image():
    path = r"/assets/img/"
    random_image = random.choice([
    x for x in os.listdir(path)
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))
])
    return random_image()
```

retailPrice_start.html

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html'%}
    {% load my_templatetag %}
    {% load static from staticfiles %}

    {% block content %}
    <h1>Actual Retail Price!</h1>
    <img src="{% static 'random_image' %}" alt""</img>
    <p>Input where player can enter amount + button to enter guess</p>
    <p>Include other players guesses via random players and amounts</p>

    <p>python will go through guess and see if player is winner, if you win you move to last and final round, if not player can play again</p>

    <form>
      <div class="form-row d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
        <div class="col-3"><i class="fas fa-user fa-5x d-flex justify-content-center"></i>
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" value="{% random_int 1 500000 %}">
          <br>

        </div>
        <div class="col-3 text-center"><i class="fas fa-user fa-5x d-flex justify-content-center"></i>
          <br>
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" value="" placeholder="Enter Price Here">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mb-2">Enter</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3"><i class="fas fa-user fa-5x d-flex justify-content-center"></i>
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" value="{% random_int 1 500000 %}">
          <br>

        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    {% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)
```

[image: Project Path]

Comment: you can put the logic of generating random img file names in view and then use the image name using static tag like `{% static random_img_name %}`

Comment: Hi @AvinashRaj - I just need a little more explanation. Are you saying to just get rid of my my_templatetag.py file and my def's there just add them into my retailPrice views.py?